# Get selected row number outside cellForRowAt indexPath method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to access the selected row outside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method. What I'm currently doing is using an `Int` to keep track of what row has been selected and assigning that value inside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` so I can later use the `Int` as the currently selected row.

Everything is working fine but I want to make sure that there is no other way of doing this without having to use the `Int` variable.

Is there a way to get the selected row number outside the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method without having to use the `Int` variable to keep track of the row number?

```
var selectedRow:Int?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
}

func myFunction(){
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:selectedRow!, section: 1)
    let cell = self.myTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `indexPathForSelectedRow`

```
guard let index =  self.myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow ,  
      let cell = self.myTable.cellForRow(at: index) as? CustomCell 
else { return }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also call your function from the didSelectRowAt delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   myFunction(forItem: indexPath.row)

}

func myFunction(forItem item: int){
   //some code
}
```